# How to check if IOTA is receiving data from device

Tags: fiware

I recently suspect I have configuration problem with the SOUTHBOUND traffic. Device already provisioned with IOTA. How do I check if the agent is receiving measurements?

Comment: Which IOTA are you using?

Comment: telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try looking in the agent's log file, to discard errors. If you do not find anything, try changing the severity of the log file to a more comprehensive value like *DEBUG*.

I have never used this FIWARE IoT Agent, but with others like [IoT Agent for the Ultralight](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul) if you configure the severity of the log file in *DEBUG* the reception of each message is shown.

If you need help to change the log file severity, start reading the agent configuration page [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/blob/master/docs/administrationGuide.md#configuration).

On the other hand, if you have your agent attached to an [Orion](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion) context broker, you should be able to validate that you are receiving data, observing how your contexts change as you receive data. For this you have the [Orion API](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#query-entity).

**EDIT:**

All FIWARE agents shares a core library called [node-lib](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib) and that component define interfaces to manage device provisioning and similar operations.

There are HTTP methods to create, fetch and delete devices and in particularly for updating a device. Check apiary blueprint [here](https://telefonicaiotiotagents.docs.apiary.io/#reference/configuration-api/device/update-a-device) for more information.

As an example:

1. Getting all devices

   curl -X GET [your_agent_host]:[port]/iot/devices
2. Update a device

   curl -X POST  [your_agent_host]:[port]/iot/devices/{device_id} -d
   '{"attributes": [{
           "object_id": "attr_id",
           "name": "attr_name",
           "type": "attr_type"} ... 
   ]}'

I think there is no way to perform a partial update on a single device, you must specify all the attributes again.

Greetings and I hope I have been of some help!

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I understand the problem is right from device provisioning. The device doesn't provisioned any active attribute, I need a way to modify it in the IoT Agent by adding the required attributes. Not sure how.

Comment: Could you paste the way you provision new devices? Also, I have edited my answer to contemplate your question about how to edit a device.

Comment: Hi I have a real device (using wakaama implementation), So my device is provisioned when I start it running **cleint -4 -h 193.136.29.17 -p 2222** 

I as soon as it is started, I see the device provision in agent (attr list empty, only lazy attr):
`$curl -X GET \
>   'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
>   -H 'fiware-service: smartGondor' \
>   -H 'fiware-servicepath: /gardens'
{"count":1,"devices":[{"device_id":"raspiSensorTV","service":"smartGondor","service_path":"/gardens","entity_name":"raspiSensorTV:Device","entity_type":"Device","attributes":[],"lazy":[{"object_id":"Short ".}`

Comment: In the response to provisioned devices query, you can see the that attributes list is empty `"attributes": [ ]` only lazy attributes are provisioned. So I would like to add temp and humidity as **active attributes** so the agent can observe their value change.